# Add lines to a local file from a Jinja2 Template with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

im a newbie to ansible and got problems with this Task.
I want to get some data from various hosts. The Idea is, to use a jinja2 template, get the data from the host and add this data in to a file local on the Ansible machine.

How is it possible to get all the data in one file on the local machine? The way i try to do it brings me the result from just one host. Thanks for your Help!

```
---
- name: "Server Report"
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "check packages"
      package_facts:
        manager: auto
    - name: "get PHP info"
      shell: "php -v | grep -E ^PHP | awk '{print $2}'"
      register: php_version
      when: "'php-common' in ansible_facts.packages"

    - name: "get MySQL info"
      shell: "mysql -V | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/,//g'"
      register: mysql_version
      when: "'mysql-common' in ansible_facts.packages"

    - name: "Use Template to create File"
      template:
        src: vrsn.j2
        dest: /opt/data.txt
      delegate_to: localhost
```

This is the Jinjer2 Code:

```
{% if ansible_facts['hostname'] is defined %}{{ ansible_facts['hostname'] }},{% else %}NoINstalled,{% endif %}
{% if ansible_facts['distribution'] is defined %}{{ ansible_facts['distribution'] }} {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] }},{% else %}NotInstalled,{% endif %}
{% if php_version.stdout is defined %}{{ php_version.stdout }},{% else %}NotInstalled,{% endif %}
{% if mysql_version.stdout is defined %}{{ mysql_version.stdout }},{% else %}NotInstalled,{% endif %}
{% if ansible_facts.packages['apache2'][0].version is defined %}
apache2-version {{ ansible_facts.packages['apache2'][0].version }},
{% elif ansible_facts.packages['apache'][0].version is defined %}
apache-version {{ ansible_facts.packages['apache'][0].version }},
{% elif ansible_facts.packages['nginx-common'][0].version is defined %}
nginx-version {{ ansible_facts.packages['nginx-common'][0].version }},
{% else %}NotInstalled{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your output format, but the following example should give you a clue to go on:
`vrsn.j2`

```
{% for h in groups['all'] %}
Inventory host: {{ h }}
hostname: {{ hostvars[h].ansible_hostname | default('N/A') }}
distribution: {{ hostvars[h].ansible_distribution | default('N/A') }}
php: {{ hostvars[h].php_version.stdout | default('N/A') }}
# add more here now you got the concept

---
{% endfor %}
```

And you should call your template like so in your play:

```yaml
    - name: "Dump all host info to local machine"
      template:
        src: vrsn.j2
        dest: /opt/data.txt
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```